# Is "further" now used for both physical and metaphorical distances?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

Is it true that 'further' and 'farther' are becoming interchangeable?

> He drove further north.
>
> His furthest destination to travel is 167 miles.

[This link](http://www.grammarmudge.cityslide.com/articles/article/992333/26400.htm) says that *further* is now widely "used and accepted in all senses, even to designate physical distance."

Comment: It seems that your question answers itself with that link. Do you have some reason to doubt it?

Comment: Yes, because it was the only site I found that mentions this. I was curious whether the trend is headed that way.

Comment: You might want to play with Google ngrams to get a sense for how common usages are in writing.

Comment: whippoorwill, your question could be improved if you mention where in the world you mean. In England and the rest of the UK, the word *further* is normal. The word *farther* is not, normally used.

Comment: In the US, they're individual variants, like _beside/besides, toward/towards, older/elder,_ etc. One can choose either, for any reason. There may be some fixed phrases where one is preferred, but there's no systematic difference between them.

Comment: I'd question a site claiming to "mudge" up grammar as an authority.

Comment: Sorry, Tristan. The US.

Comment: My question is whether the *further/farther* distinction in meaning existed before the grammarians started telling everybody which one to use when.

Comment: [This Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=further+end%2Ffurther%2Cfarther+end%2Ffarther&year_start=1680&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=30&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28further%20end%20/%20further%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28farther%20end%20/%20farther%29%3B%2Cc0) seems to indicate there was no distinction between *further* and *farther* before 1750 or so. I'm willing to bet that's when this grammatical advice was first offered.

Comment: whippoorwill, you should edit your question to include that.

Answer (score 1):

The distinction in meaning still *technically* exists but colloquial usage doesn't really care and just picks one. You can still find plenty of guides online detailing which is more appropriate but more modern articles are beginning to include paragraphs such as the following from [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/further-versus-farther?page=all):

> The good news is that in ambiguous cases it doesn't matter which word you choose. Although careful writers will try to stick with the distinction between "further" and "farther," **the Oxford English Dictionary, Fowler's Modern English Usage, and a number of other sources say that, in most cases, it's fine to use "further" and "farther" interchangeably**, especially when the distinction isn't clear. People have been using them interchangeably for hundreds of years.

So, to directly answer your question:

> Is it true that 'further' and 'farther' are becoming interchangeable?

They have been used interchangeably for ages in spite of the pedantic distinction between the two meanings. So, they aren't *becoming* interchangeable; they already *are* interchangeable.

Comment: So is farther and further getting closer or digressing?

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd: Their meanings are converging.

Comment: Can I work on farthering my career?

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd: Whether "farthering" should suddenly be considered a word is kind of a separate issue. :)

Comment: Ha that is nitpicky - could I say, "How do I farther my career at this company?"  I am sure my boss would say, "Step 1, quit speaking Engrish."

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd: Colloquially, yes you can say that. But if your boss happens to be pedantic about the meanings of words such as farther/further then you should probably appease them. As the article I linked notes, when in doubt, use "further."